# How to import WasmMemory without a bundler?

Tags: javascript, webassembly, rust-wasm

I was following the tutorial on making a WASM application with Rust. I decided on not using a bundler, but I stumbled upon a question. When using a bundler, to access WASM's memory, I can simply `import { memory } from "<package>/<package>_bg"`, but without it, I can't make it work. What I'm doing:

```
import init , * as wasm from "./wasm/inner.js";

async function run() {
    await init();

    window.wasm = wasm;
    wasm.debug_mode();
}

run();
```

This code works, and I can call Rust's functions easily. The problem is accessing WASM's memory. How do I get a reference to it, or something? Is it even possible? I stumbled upon  the possibility of doing `let wasm = await init();`, but the methods inside this object don't work, neither does the `memory` object inside of it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to import memory. You can access memory through `let wasm = await init();`. E.g.

```
import init , * as my_inner from "./wasm/inner.js";

let wasm;
let memory;

async function run() {
    wasm = await init();
    memory = wasm.memory;
    window.wasm = my_inner;
    my_inner.debug_mode();
}

run();
```

Note: I am also learning wasm+rust without npm so my code style may be incorrect e.g. `my_inner`. I have been importing functions via `import { function_name } from ...`.

I found this information from this tutorial covering using rust+wasm without npm: https://lionturkey.github.io/posts/rustwasm/rustwasm.html